# How to multiply negative numbers in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, programming

This is my script for multiplying negative numbers

```
#!/bin/bash

p="1"
h="-10"
z=$(echo "(($p)*($h)+2"| bc -l)
echo $p $h $z
```

and this is the result

```
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
1 -10
```

how to multiply negative numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 3 opening left parentheses, but only 2 closing right ones.

```
z=$(echo "($p)*($h)+2" | bc -l)
```

In fact, you don't need any parentheses:

```
z=$(echo "$p*$h+2" | bc -l)
```

Comment: *4 opening and 3 closing